# Browsersync + gulp-watch not working

Tags: javascript, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

In my project i use gulp + browsersync. After update gulp v.4.0.0., browsersync not working and my styles not compiled when watch run (only after in manual restart `gulp watch`).

This is my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
sass = require('gulp-sass'),
browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
concat = require('gulp-concat'),
uglify = require('gulp-uglifyjs'),
cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano'),
rename = require('gulp-rename'),
del = require('del'),
imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant'),
autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions', '> 1%'], {cascade: true}))
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
 });

gulp.task('css-libs', gulp.parallel('sass'), function(){
return gulp.src('app/css/main.css')
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'));
});


gulp.task('browser-sync', function(){
browserSync({
    server: {
        //baseDir: 'app'
        baseDir: './'
    },
    notify:false
})
});


gulp.task('watch', gulp.parallel('browser-sync', 'css-libs'), function(){
gulp.watch('app/scss/*.scss', ['sass']);
gulp.watch('*.html', browserSync.reload);
});
```

How to fix it?

**UPD**

This is my [`package.json`](https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/rafhtz9o/)

Gulp-watch not working when i [change scss file](https://i.gyazo.com/9ad5410c312726d12a22d5be4556db27.png).

Comment: It's better if you could provide the complete info. including your package.json and the error message you are getting. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @JacobGoh i have no errors. its working fine, but gulp-watch not working. i update my question

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: @CodeGust no, i go back to the previous version

Answer (score 2):

I believe your 'watch' task should be rewritten like so:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function(){

  // note the .init

  browserSync.init({
      server: {
          //baseDir: 'app'
          baseDir: './'
      },
      notify:false
  })
});

gulp.task('watch', gulp.parallel('browser-sync', 'css-libs', function(done){

   //   change in the previous line and the following line

  gulp.watch('app/scss/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
  gulp.watch('*.html', browserSync.reload);
  done();
}));
```

so that the function call with the watches is part of the gulp.parallel call.  See the [parallel tasks documentation](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/4.0/docs/API.md#gulpparalleltasks) and [gulp.task signature](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/4.0/docs/API.md#gulptaskname-fn).

```
gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('one', 'two', function(done) {
  // do more stuff
  done();
}));
```

Comment: i already try it, but watch still not working when i change scss file https://i.gyazo.com/9ad5410c312726d12a22d5be4556db27.png

Comment: So are you saying when you modify a scss file that the 'sass' task is not triggered?  And you tried my suggested code exactly.

Comment: Okay, I made a couple more changes to my answer above after testing this.   This works perfectly for me.